# How to install latest Bluefish

Tags: 11.10, text-editor, bluefish

I am trying to install the latest Bluefish 2.2.0 in 11.10 but all I find is the repositories for the older versions of Ubuntu. Is there any place to find the a PPA or deb package for 11.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The klaus-vormweg PPA is no longer resolving, so to get the newest version, I had to add flatpaks to Software Center:

```
sudo apt install flatpak gnome-software-plugin-flatpak gnome-software  
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
```

Then restart your computer, log in, and search for Bluefish in the Software Center and install the flatpak version (see arrow below):

[image]

At this time of this writing, the flatpak was on version 2.2.12, and the Ubuntu Bionic Universe repo was on version 2.2.10.

If you find this helpful, please consider leaving an up-vote.

Answer (score 8):

I know your question has already been answered, but if you want, for quick reference, these are the commands to install the latest version of Bluefish (using Terminal):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:klaus-vormweg/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bluefish
```

Answer (score 2):

https://launchpad.net/~klaus-vormweg/+archive/ppa

https://launchpad.net/~klaus-vormweg/+archive/ppa/+sourcepub/2086778/+listing-archive-extra

Comment: Many thanks. You just saved me a couple of hours of work.

Comment: you are most welcome.